# javascript calling a function expression itself from inside it with arguments

Tags: javascript, function, math

Please, someone, tell me how is the result 384 here.
According to me:
Called function value is greater than 2 so, the result should be 
8 * fac(8 - 2)
64-2
ans: 62
I understand something happening with "fac" please explain.

```
let factoria = function fac(n){
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 2);
}

console.log(factoria(8));
// result 384
```

Comment: Work out the steps, and you'll see it. It's called recursion. 8x6x4x2=384

Comment: How did you get from `8*fac(8 - 2)` to `64 - 2`?.  `8*fac(8 - 2)` is not `8*8 - 2`. It's `8*fac(6)`.

Answer (score 0):

This line `n * fac(n - 2)` is recursively calling the itself with new value. At first it will be called with `8 * fac(8 - 2)`so now `fac` will be called again with 6, then again with 4 and so on

```js
let factoria = function fac(n) {
  console.log(n)
  return n < 2 ? 1 : n * fac(n - 2); // recursive function 
}

console.log(factoria(8));
```

Comment: Thank you :). This was very helpful. Now I know how the Recursion works.